# UICollectionView App crashes showing large number of images on iPhone

Tags: ios, sdk, uiimageview, uicollectionview

I need to display around 300 images on UICollectionView. I have added custom UICollectionViewCell and subview UIImageView, now when i try to display images on UICollectionView from web server it display around 150 images and then app crashes showing low  level memory. Below is my code, please let me know what i am doing wrong.

```
-(void)updateView {

    for (int i = 0; i < m_nPhotoCount; i ++)
    {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

            NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[aryList objectAtIndex:i]];
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL]];
            if(image == nil)
            {
                NSLog(@"kashif");
            }
            else {
                [self.imageArray addObject:image];
            }
            dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [collectionView reloadData];
            });
        });
    }
}

    #pragma mark - UICollectionView Datasource

    - (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)view numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

        return [self.imageArray count];
    }


    - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"GalleryCell";
        GalleryCell *cell = (GalleryCell*)[cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.imageView.image = [self.imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        return cell;
    }

    - (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        return [[UICollectionReusableView alloc] init];

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are taking up the wrong approach. What you should do is, You should download only those number of images (equivalent to number of visible cells of CollectionView) at once.

When collection view is scrolled than download more images and purge or store previous images in the cache.

You can make use of this wonderful Image Downloading and caching library : [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)

Comment: Hello previously i have tried SDWebImage using UITableView it didn't work, would you please help me out with UICollectionView for caching.

Comment: @user1237473 what do you mean by "It Didn't Work", You imported that UITableView specific image caching header file in your viewController for caching the images in Tableview?

Answer (score 0):

There are special libraries available for gallery. You should try library rather handling or creating collection view with large size.